# Adding mysql data in Google Maps infowindow

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I have displayed markers on a map via lat and long in a database. I would now like the other rows, correspinding to that users lat and long, to display in the info window. E.g. their name, ID. How would I go about this?

```
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: " .$member" + ".$memberID" (<<< something like that)

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(dis.latitude,dis.longitude),
    map: maps
    }))

infowindow.open(window.googleMap,marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right idea. In order to do this, you will need to store the values which are in your database inside some vars. Similar to what you did with the lat and long in your DB. Also, It's usually recommended to first create a string containing everything you want to go inside of the infowindow. Lets assume you have variables named member and ID which hold your values from the database that you want in the infowindow. You could do something like so:

```
var contentString = 'some content' + member + 'other content' + ID;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(dis.latitude,dis.longitude),
map: map
}));

marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

This will make it so that the infowindow will be displayed when you click the marker. If you wish it to be displayed at the same time as the marker is put in the map, you don't need to add the listener to your marker, you can just call:

```
infowindow.open(map.marker)
```

Directly after you create the marker. I have this demonstrated in a JSFiddle here, I have commented out the code that adds a listener to the marker so that the infowindow displays right away. Note that you will need to insert your own API key for this to work. See fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/c01xxg29/

There is also a good document on infowindows here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction

I hope this helps!